# How to define global logger for whole application?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have application with several classes each one has own logger (`Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.class)`). Each class has methods which need to be logged.

Is there any way to define logger (instead "this.class") to make all classes  logged into one appender (one file) ?

It would be great if it can be done with help of VM option, like `-Dlog4j.configuration=...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you have a separate instance of `Logger` for each file doesn't mean that they get logged to a different file. In fact, they typically aren't. The only purpose of giving the class as argument to `getLogger()` method is to give it a *name* (in this case the name of your class with all packages).

The name has two purposes: First, it can be logged in your messages like this:

```
[main] INFO  MyApp  - Entering application.
[main] DEBUG com.foo.Bar  - Did it again!
[main] INFO  MyApp  - Exiting application.
```

Second, you can use it for more fine-grained configuration of log4j:

```
# Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package com.foo.
log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN
```

The file where logs are written can be controlled in configuration, e.g., like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=myfile
log4j.appender.myfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myfile.File=example.log
```

You can just read the [manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) for more info.

---

If for some reason you didn't want to tie the logger to your class, you can always call [`Logger.getRootLogger()`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html#getRootLogger) which returns a logger with the special default name `ROOT`.